# How to redirct prorgram STDOUT/ERR to different location than /usr/bin/time STDOUT/ERR

Tags: bash, shell, time

Take something as simple as

```
/usr/bin/time ls -l
```

Lets say I want to redirect like so

```
lsstdout=a.out
lsstderr=b.err
timestdout=c.out
timestderr=d.err
```

How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this if you don't mind running `ls` with another `bash`:

```
/usr/bin/time bash -c 'ls -l > ls.out 2> ls.err' > time.out 2> time.err
```